# Architecture and project organization

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, architecture

We are, in my company, at the beginning of a huge refactoring to migrate from home made database access to Hibernate.
We want to do it clean, and therefore we wiil use entities, DAOs, etc...
We use maven, and we will therefore have two maven projects, one for the entities, one for the DAOs (is it good, or is it better to have both in the same project ?).

Knowing that, our question is the following : our business layer will use the DAOs. 
As most of the DAO's methods return entities, our business layer will have to know about entities. And therefore, our business layer will have to know about Hibernate, as our entities will be Hibernate annotated (or at least JPA annotated).
Is this a problem ? If yes, what is the solution to give the business layer the very minimum knowledge about the data layer ?

Thank you,

Seb

Comment: Are you really need annotation-based mapping? It can be done using XML, thus JPA nature of objects will be fully hidden: http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Mapping-Columns-and-Mapping-Files-with-Hibernate-35

Comment: it might be better to have entities and daos share a project. that way the entities get exercised in the process of testing the daos. and it's ok to let the service layer know about the entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I typically model the dependencies, along with the reasoning.

1. Let's distinguish 4 things:

   a. the business logic

   b. entities

   c. DAO interfaces

   d. DAO implementations
2. For me the first three belong together and therefor belong in the same maven module, AND even in the same package. They are closely related and a change in one will very likely cause a change in the other. And things that change together should be close together.
3. the implementation of the DAO is to a large extend independent of the business logic. And even more important the business logic should NOT depend on where the data is coming from. It is a completely separate concern. So if your data comes today from a database and tomorrow from a webservice, nothing should change in your business logic.
4. You are right, Hibernate (or JPA) annotations on the enities violate that rule to some extent. You have three options:

   a. Live with it. While it creates a dependency to Hibernate artifacts, it does not create a dependency on any Hibernate implementation. So in most scenarios, having the annotations around is acceptable

   b. use xml configuration. This will fix the dependency issue, but in my opinion at the rather hefty cost of dealing with xml based configuration. Not worth it in my opinion

   c. Don't use Hibernate. I don't think the dependency on Annotations is the important problem you have to consider. The more serious problem is, that Hibernate is rather invasive. When you navigate an object graph, Hibernate will trigger lazy loading, i.e. the execution of sql statements at points that are not at all obvious from looking at the code. This basically means, you data access code starts to leak into every part of the application if you are not careful. One can keep this contained, but it is not easy and requires great care and a in depth understanding of Hibernate, that most teams don't have when they start with it. So Hibernate (or JPA) trades a simple but tedious task of writing SQL-Statments with a difficult task of creating a software architecture, that keeps mostly invisible dependencies in check. I therefore would recommend avoid Hiberante at all and try something simpler. I personally have high hopes toward MyBatis, but haven't used it in real projects yet.
5. More important then managing the dependencies between technical layers is in my opinion the separation of domain modules. [And I'm not alone with that opinion](http://olivergierke.de/2013/01/whoops-where-did-my-architecture-go/).
6. I would use separate artifacts (i.e. maven modules) only to separate things that you want to deploy independently. If you for example have a rich client and a backend server two maven artifacts for those, plus maybe a third one for common code make sens. For everything else I'd simply use packages and tests that fail when illegal dependencies get created. For those I use [Degraph](http://schauder.github.io/degraph/), but I'm the author of that so I might be biased.

Comment: Parts of this post are in my opinion outdated and are managed nowadays by higher abstracted concepts. But lets keep this aside.
Not using hibernate is not a solution. Just learn how it works and don't try to put every annotation you know on top of any relation. Don't create interfaces for the daos as long as you don't have an usecase for that. Its a nice argument, but usually in reality nobody changes the whole way how to access data. You can't abstract that, because the way this layer works internally has an impact for the whole application.

Comment: @mh-dev so what are the higher abstracted concepts?

Comment: For example the data layer. Nobody will ever use the same interface to access data with a JPA and an Elasticsearch implementation. Also nobody will ever swap the JPA implementation. The same for Messaging. All of them behave different and must be treated accordingly. You kept the Controller layer out which plays huge role. The architectural magic knowdays comes from intelligent injection mechanisms wirring things together implicitly. I know its hard to describe, but Spring goes exactly into this direction right now.

Comment: @mh-dev sorry but this is completely backwards: 1. different technologies aren't higher abstractions, but different details. 2. Yes if you know your job you do over those, using interfaces. 3. Controllers have nothing to do with the OPs question. 4. Injection mechanisms don't replace anything I mentioned, but enable it.

Comment: They do thats the reason why its a higher abstract level. Because you have completly different possibilities to wirre and organize things together. I use interfaces where they have purpose and not to have them to maybe do something in a year with them. For me I am out, just wanted to ensure that a reader of the answer might be aware that there might be other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers